# Python Error too many arguements

Tags: python

I am writing a program to create, change, and solve a 15-puzzle and I'm stuck on what I assumed would be the easy part. So I have a Board class that creates a solved 15-puzzle by default. Then I have a set_board function that takes 16 integers and puts them into the puzzle instead of the defaults. But when I run the function it says that I provided too many arguments( set_board() takes exactly 16 arguments (17 given)) even though i entered the integers 0 through 16(* here takes the place of zero so it is easy to see). Either I'm seeing things from staring at the screen for too long or I'm misunderstanding something. Can someone help?

```
    def set_board(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p):
        self.board = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p]]
```

And in the shell:

```
    board.set_board('*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
        board.set_board('*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
    TypeError: set_board() takes exactly 16 arguments (17 given)
```

Comment: Can't replicate works fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

When you define a method of a class in Python the first argument should be "self".  Python is passing this in for you, hence the 17 args given.

Use:

```
def set_board(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p):
        self.board = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p]]
```

Comment: Yep, saw it after walking away for a minute. Thanks for the help anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to treat

```
board.set_board('*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

as

```
set_board(board, '*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

so you have 17 arguments. And it is why we define methods as `set_board(self, ....)`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I see my simple error. I forgot to include self in the declaration of the function. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

When you call 
`board.set_board('*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`

python actually sends one extra "argument" to the function - the object `board`. So, your 16 explicit arguments, plus the implicit argument `board` make 17. To fix this, you probably want to change your function declaration to this:

```
def set_board(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p):
    self.board = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p]]
```

Making the first argument `self` allows python to send a reference to the object that owns the function instance to the scope of the function.

Comment: Yea I saw that after i walked away for a second and came back. Brain is fried today, thanks for the help anyway :D